# Travel with expired passport

Tags: passports, germany, expired

I’ll be travelling from Australia to Germany in February and my German passport expired in October 2022. I’m a German citizen and hold no other valid passport.

I called the German embassy and I’m definitely ok to enter Germany but I’m worried the airline (Qatar Airways) won’t let me on the plane. I rang them and they keep telling me I need to check with the German embassy.

Anyone got any experience or tips?

Comment: You are supposed to make a new passport in a German consulate of embassy near your residence. You can't travel with an expired passport.

Comment: @André Traveling home to your country of citizenship is a special case, but it can still be tricky.

Comment: For that you can use also a travel document or emergency passport. An expired passport is still useless for traveling.

Comment: Do you have a currently valid German ID card?

Answer (score 8):

Apply for a **Provisional passport**

- [Vorläufige Reisepässe - Auswärtiges Amt](https://australien.diplo.de/au-de/service/02-reisepaesse/vorlaeufiger-reisepass/2067560) (in German)

  - German Missions in Australia

This is non-biometric passport that can be issued directly by the consulate, but is not always accepted by all countries which require a biometric passport.

Comment: The OP still has a month plus, why not just get a regular passport?

Comment: @lambshaanxy German biometric passports are only printed in the [Bundesdruckerei](https://www.bundesdruckerei.de/en) in Berlin. Even when applying inside Germany it can take 4-6 weeks.

Comment: I only have experience with French passports and Consulates, but applying overseas for a French passport is usually faster than back home. Last month I hot a new one in 10 days. The process is streamlined compared to home. Might be worth enquiring with the Consulate.

Comment: @dda The real question here is why the OP just didn't ask about this in the first place when calling the German embassy. They would have known how long it might take and had offered the *provisional passport* as an alternative.

Comment: Very likely the person on the phone didn't know or didn't bother to think about it.

Comment: @André That is my point, the wrong question was being asked.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I can't even imagine a German administration that would be anywhere near _that_ fast

Comment: @njzk2 The application procees is actually quite swift. It is all done electronically, no forms to fill out since the registry office already has your data and takes about 10 minutes. The electronic document is then sent to the Bundesdruckerei (which prints passports, ID, drivers licenses, national certificates, banknotes etc.). The physical document is then sent to the registry office where they then send you per snailpost a letter informing you that you can pick it up. My last passport/ID took about 3 weeks. So it is more a combination of how much must be be printed and transport